# How to create a list of resolved injected dependencies in C#

Tags: c#, ninject

I wanted to know if there is a way I can get all the resolved dependencies into a list. For eg.

```
public class A
 {
   Interface1 _X;
   Interface2 _Y;

   public A(Interface1 X, Interface2 Y)
 {
    _X = X;
    _Y = Y;
 }
}
```

Here _X and _Y will be resolved to actual classes by NInject.

How do I get them in a list so that I can pass it around? My main intent is to have all the resolved dependencies in some container so its convinient to pass them all, in some method.

Comment: Where is the `List`? Your code snippet has no `List`.
You may write some pseudo code to show want you want to achieve.

Comment: It could work if : Interface1 and Interface2 both inherit from Interface0, and you have bound implementations also on interface0, and your parameter constructor for A is of type IEnumerable<Interface0>